# Number exercises according to chapter

Tags: numbering, memoir, counters, exercises

I'm using the `exercise` package together with `memoir` class. How do I number my exercises according to chapter number, in the same way that display equations are numbered? Here's a minimal example

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{exercise}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Foo}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        \begin{Exercise}
            This should come out as Exercise 1.1
        \end{Exercise}
        \begin{Answer}
            Answer 1.1
        \end{Answer}

        \begin{Exercise}
            This should be Exercise 1.2
        \end{Exercise}

    \chapter{Bar}
        Consectetuer adipiscing elit
        \begin{Exercise}
            And this should be Exercise 2.1
        \end{Exercise}

        \begin{Exercise}
            Certainly this should be Exercise 2.2
        \end{Exercise}
        \begin{Answer}
            Answer 2.2
        \end{Answer}
\end{document}
```

I'm thinking of tapping into a counter variable in `memoir` or somewhere else. How do I go about it? I would like the numbering to also affect the `Answer` environment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess that

```
\usepackage{exercise,chngcntr}
\counterwithin{Exercise}{chapter}
\counterwithin{Answer}{chapter}
```

should do what you need. The **chngcntr** package is used for binding a counter to another or to free one from another (with `\counterwithout`).

Answer (score 10):

The [`exercise` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/exercise) provides the `Exercise` counter. Therefore, if you want the exercises numbered according to the chapter counter, you need:

```
\renewcounter{Exercise}[chapter]% Reset counter every chapter
\renewcommand{\theExercise}{\thechapter.\arabic{Exercise}}%
```

[image: Exercise & answer]

For any future reference on counters (how to reset them, so-called "master and slave" countering), consider reading the following TeX FAQ entries:

- [Redefining counters’ \the-commands](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-the-commands)
- [Master and slave counters](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-addtoreset)

Comment: To help with future applications, what reference manual can I look up usage of `\thechapter`? (I found `\arabic` in vim-LaTeX Suite `:help arabic`)

Comment: @Kit: I've added 2 references to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing or happy to use the `amsmath` package, you could also set

```
\usepackage{amsmath,exercise}
\numberwithin{Answer}{chapter}
\numberwithin{Exercise}{chapter}
```