# Adding exercises numbered according to the sections at the end of the sections

Tags: numbering, exercises

I want to add exercises numbered according to the sections at the end of the sections (as in the picture below) how can I do it?

[image]

My code is that

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{makeidx}
 \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{stmaryrd}
 \usepackage{tasks}
 \usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
 \usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{xypic}
 \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepackage{xcolor}
 \usepackage{mwe}

  \usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes, arrows, 
  arrows.meta, decorations.markings, patterns, datavisualization}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween, polar}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
   \usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
  \pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=
    middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }}
  \linespread{1.5}
  \newtheorem{theorem}{Teorem}
  \newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
  \newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
  \newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
  \newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
  \newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
  \newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Sonu\c{c}}
  \newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
  \newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
  \newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Sonu\c{c}}
  \newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
  \newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Tan\i m}
  \newtheorem{example}[theorem]{\"{O}rnek}

  \newenvironment{proof}[1][Kan\i t]{\noindent\text{#1:} }{$\square$}
  \newenvironment{remark}[1][Not]{\noindent\textbf{#1:} }{}
  \newenvironment{solution}[1][\c{C}\"{o}z\"{u}m]{\noindent\text{#1:} } 
   {}
  \renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}
  \makeatletter

  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{5}
  \setlist[exercise] 
  {label*=\thesection.\arabic*.,ref=\thesection.\arabic*,before= 
  {\subsection*{Exercises}}}

  \begin{document}


  \section{Section 1}

  \subsection{Subsection 1}

  \begin{exercise}


  \item A

  \item B

  \item C

  \end{exercise}

  \subsection{Subsection 2}

  \begin{exercise}


  \item E

  \item F

  \item G

  \end{exercise}

  \section{Section 2}

  \subsection{Subsection 3}

  \begin{exercise}

  \item H

  \item I

  \item J

  \end{exercise}

  \subsection{Subsection 4}

  \begin{exercise}
  \item K
  \item L

  \item M

  \end{exercise}

  \end{document}
```

But it produces, not exactly what i want

[image]

Comment: There is a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27444/number-exercises-according-to-chapter). Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @Celdor I don't exactly want something like this

Comment: As you load `enumitem` package, you can append `[resume]` to `\begin{exercise}` as in `\begin{exercise}[resume]` to continue numbering (see p. 9 of [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem))

Comment: @Celdor Thank you for your answer. In which environment should I do this while writing in the Scientific Workplace 5.5 program?

Comment: I don't use this application and really don't know how to help you with that. Check one of its [manuals](https://www.sciword.co.uk/manuals.htm). I assume there's a context menu with "additional options" or "custom arguments", in which you should add `resume`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things should be done.

(1) Add `resume` to    the `\setlist[exercise]{...`  to continue numbering between subsections; and then

(2) reset the numbering to 1 in each section (with `\restartlist{exercise}`).

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex 
 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xypic}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes, arrows, 
    arrows.meta, decorations.markings, patterns, datavisualization}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween, polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=
        middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }}
\linespread{1.5}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Teorem}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[theorem]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[theorem]{Case}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[theorem]{Sonu\c{c}}
\newtheorem{condition}[theorem]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Sonu\c{c}}
\newtheorem{criterion}[theorem]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Tan\i m}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{\"{O}rnek}

\newenvironment{proof}[1][Kan\i t]{\noindent\text{#1:} }{$\square$}
\newenvironment{remark}[1][Not]{\noindent\textbf{#1:} }{}
\newenvironment{solution}[1][\c{C}\"{o}z\"{u}m]{\noindent\text{#1:} } 
{}
\renewcommand{\dateseparator}{.}
\makeatletter

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercise] 
{label*=\thesection.\arabic*.,
    ref=\thesection.\arabic*,
    before=     {\subsection*{Exercises}},
    resume % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\restartlist{exercise}\oldsection} % added <<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}    

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{exercise}    
    \item A 
    \item B 
    \item C 
\end{exercise}

\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{exercise}    
    \item E 
    \item F 
    \item G 
\end{exercise}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}

\begin{exercise}
    \item H 
    \item I 
    \item J 
\end{exercise}

\subsection{Subsection 4}
\begin{exercise}
    \item K
    \item L 
    \item M 
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** After follow-up question

It is not necessary to define a new list. In this example `enumerate` is used instead of `exercise`

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex 
 
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate] 
{label*=\thesection.\arabic*.,
    ref=\thesection.\arabic*,
    before=     {\subsection*{Exercises}},  
    resume, % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  
}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\restartlist{enumerate}\oldsection} % added <<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}    

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{enumerate}   
    \item A 
    \item B 
    \item C 
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Subsection 2}
\begin{enumerate}   
    \item E 
    \item F 
    \item G 
\end{enumerate}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item H 
    \item I 
    \item J 
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Subsection 4}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item K
    \item L 
    \item M 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question. Is it possible to use enumarate instead of exercise?

Comment: @Mehmet Onat Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers

Comment: Your answer is enough for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is another question. *https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659762/numbering-the-exercises-at-the-end-of-the-sections-according-to-the-sections*