# Numbering the exercises at the end of the sections according to the sections

Tags: numbering, enumerate

I want to add exercises numbered according to the sections at the end of the sections and subsections of the book I wrote. The code below helps to do this, but it gives an error in enviroments such as theorem or corollary. I want to use enumarate between `\begin{theorem}` and `\end{theorem}` or like `\begin{corollary}` and `\end{corollary}`. In this case, I want it to call numbers like 1,2,3. How can I solve this problem?

```
\setlist[enumerate] 
     {label*=\thesection.\arabic*.,
     ref=\thesection.\arabic*,
     before=     {\subsection*{Exercise}},  
     resume, 
      }
    \let\oldsection\section
    \renewcommand{\section}{\restartlist{enumerate}\oldsection}
```

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{enumitem}


 \setlist[enumerate] 
 {label*=\thesection.\arabic*.,
 ref=\thesection.\arabic*,
 before=     {\subsection*{Exercise}},  
 resume, 
 }
 \let\oldsection\section
 \renewcommand{\section}{\restartlist{enumerate}\oldsection} 

 \begin{document}


 \section{Section 1}

 \subsection{Subsection 1}

 \begin{enumerate}
 \item A

 \item B

 \item C
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\begin{enumerate}
\item E

\item F

\item G
\end{enumerate}

\section{Section 2}

\subsection{Subsection 3}

\begin{enumerate}
\item H

\item I

\item J
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Subsection 4}

\begin{enumerate}
\item K

\item L

\item M


\end{enumerate}

 \begin{theorem}
 $X$ be a space

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item a

 \item b

 \item c
\end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to define the `theorem` (or `corollary`) environment(s). But in order to provide some contextual difference between a regular `enumerate` and something you want to use for exercises, define a new list (called `exercises`) that you use explicitly for that purpose. This way they each have a different counter associated with them and can be used independently (even an `enumerate` inside an `exercises`, for example).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newlist{exercises}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[exercises]{
  label*=\thesection.\arabic*.,
  ref=\thesection.\arabic*,
  before= {\subsection*{Exercise}},  
  resume
 }
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}{\restartlist{exercises}\oldsection} 

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{exercises}
  \item A
  \item B
  \item C
\end{exercises}

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\begin{exercises}
  \item E
  \item F
  \item G
\end{exercises}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 3}

\begin{exercises}
  \item H
  \item I
  \item J
\end{exercises}

\subsection{Subsection 4}

\begin{exercises}
  \item K
  \item L
  \item M
\end{exercises}

\begin{theorem}
  Let\ $X$ be a space
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
  \end{enumerate}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using the following code to start new chapters in a book from a single page: \renewcommand{\section}{\cleardoublepage\oldsection}. What can I do to use these two codes together? \renewcommand{\section}{\restartlist{exercises}\oldsection}  and \renewcommand{\section}{\cleardoublepage\oldsection}

Comment: @MehmetOnat: `\renewcommand{\section}{\cleardoublepage\restartlist{exercises}\oldsection}`

Comment: Thank you so much